# Show command prompt including commands issued before entering neovim

Tags: neovim, command-line, original-vim

I've been using vim for a long time and got used to issuing:

```
:!
```

to peek at the command prompt *behind* the vim "window" working on Terminal.app in Mac OS where I can see old commands and their outputs.

I'm attempting to switch to neovim, but issuing just `:!` appears to behave differently and shows nothing but a blank line below the neovim command prompt.

Is there a way to see the former commands and output in neovim?

Comment: You may want `:suspend` or C-z

Comment: oh, I didn't think to do it that way. Then I can issue `fg` to go back. Not bad.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `:suspend` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>, which put vim in the background, returning you to the shell from which you launched it. Then use your shell's normal job-control commands to return (*e.g.*, `fg`).